# Build not get updated only version number changed in windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-store

I am trying to update the version of windows phone app.The site shows that version has been updated on site but the build never gets updated although i am sure that we are using the latest build that we want to change.The version number in our VC and publisher account is also same.Please let me know the what could be the problem or any exact link or video to update the version

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/months-of-year-learning-for-kids-toddlers/1e805232-20b5-4119-a475-56ccc56c5c8a

Now you can see that description and icon get updated but the build have the same icon as our old one does

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I usually set it in a couple of places, MMAppManifest.xml -> Packaging -> Version

And

Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: I would check it out and let you know Thanks

Comment: Please if u change it any other places let me know about that too?

Comment: Same result funks any other idea?